# Removing nested api call from for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

i made an api call to return a set of data(ex: users - list type, with the returned data i created a for loop and and within my for loop i make another api call to get the user's profile detail based on the user's id. I know this isn't the best practice and i was wondering how i could go about refactoring it.

```
api.get(...).then(response => { 
   this.users = response; 
   for(let i=0; i<this.users.length; i++){
     api.get(...this.users[i].id).then(response => {
       if(response.name == this.users[i].name)
         this.newList.push(response);
     })
   }
})
```

and in my html i loop over this.newList to display the info that i need.

How can i remove the nested api call from within the for loop and still get the same results?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're looking for. It depends a lot on what you're using this for and how data is stored on the API. Is it possible you could provide more information? The 2 possible solutions I see are either moving this code to the server, or making a system where you send the second call only when it is actually needed - but this second solution will greatly depend on the application.

Comment: Do you have access to the Backend, if you do, alter the logic to accept multiple IDs. Then you can just send all IDs once and get all profiles, then match the profiles here

Comment: Maybe you can use, async/await, and forEach just to make the code more readable. To optimise this, i think you need to work on the backend, if it's your API

Comment: I agree with @LachlanWalls and jonathan as well. Just create an api which should send you all the details rather than you making so many calls. Now how you load the data is another thing you might have to address.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Although this will not remove nested loop, but make code look better

Example

```
async function getUsersAndProfiles () {
    try {
        this.users = await api.get(...); 
        for(let i=0; i<this.users.length; i++){
            let response = await api.get(...this.users[i].id);
            if (response.name == this.users[i].name)
                this.newList.push(response);
        }
    }
    catch (e)
        console.log(e);
}
```

You can even move api call for user profile to another async function for possible future reuse and better code structure

Answer (score 0):

Just push array of request into array after that we can use Promise.all() to make a request at a time, then we could create newList based on results array.

```
 api.get(...).then(response => {
    this.users = response;
    const promises = this.users.map(user => api.get(...user.id))
    const result = Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
        this.newList = results.filter((user, i) => user.name === this.users[i].name)
    })
})
```